# Xamarin Android: Cannot choose compile version

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

If I want to choose an Item from the "Compile using Android Version" Dropdown, the only item I can choose is "Use latest Platform".

[image: Android Versions]

I installed the following SDK packages:

[image: SKDs]

Shouldn't the program give me other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like Visual Studio doesn't recognize your Android SDK.

Check the path of your Android JDK, SDK, NDK under Tools > Options > Xamarin > Android Settings, and make sure you point them to their correct locations.

Comment: All of them seem fine to me

Comment: You should try reinstalling JDK & SDK then

Comment: Also all packages or only the program itself?

Comment: @DieterMüller I would recommend everything, including the JDK, SDK and the packages.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it

Comment: I have the same problem. Did this answer work as accepted, or did you have to do something else too?